# Use GET to return records based on nested fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to retrieve records based on a value in a mongo dataset that is in a nested object.

`data` is an object and `documentId` is a field within it and I want to retrieve just the objects within data that have the `documentId` of  "5da713edf0a1645ae95b11oo"

I tried this code

```
const res = await axios.get('/api/card',{
  params:{
    data:documentId: "5da713edf0a1645ae95b11oo"
  }
});
```

but it just returns all the records

Comment: Do you need to enclose `"data:documentId"` in quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of these:

```
const res = await axios.get('/api/card',{
  params:{
    documentId: "5da713edf0a1645ae95b11oo"
  }
});
```

This would be a GET request to `/api/card?documentId=5da713edf0a1645ae95b11oo`

or

```
const res = await axios.get('/api/card',{
  params:{
    data: {
      documentId: "5da713edf0a1645ae95b11oo"
    }
  }
});
```

This would be a GET request to something like `/api/card?data=%7B%22documentId%22%3A%225da713edf0a1645ae95b11oo%22%7D`

...where `%7B%22documentId%22%3A%225da713edf0a1645ae95b11oo%22%7D` is URL encoded version of `{"documentId":"5da713edf0a1645ae95b11oo"}`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
data_get() {
    axios.get('/api/card')
    .then((res) => {
        this.setState({
            documentId: res.data.id, //5da713edf0a1645ae95b11oo 
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Please provide a bit of context. Why does that solve the problem? Where should that function go?

Answer (score 0):

according to the documentations it says that we can not do what you have done.

```
axios.get('/api/card')
.then((res) => {
    const data = res.data.id;
    //handle your response here.
    //can write your logic to retrieve your specific data 
});
```

for further in formations refer this [doc](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosgeturl-config)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume the data you're receiving on the response is an array of objects. You can filter through it. You're going to have to loop through the data though.

```
const res = await axios.get('/api/card')

const filteredData = res.data.filter((item) => item.documentId === '5da713edf0a1645ae95b11oo')
```